# How to protect our module with serial number or other way

Tags: module

We developed a module but want to make only few people can use our module

Is there any way to make this? (e.g. adding serial number like some extension company do)

(so even if someone got copy of all files, he can't use without our permission)

Comment: Usually this is not worth the effort, you must take into account agencies who buy the module can use the module on multiple domains, different staging environments, different developer environments, continuous integration, automated testing environments, etc. And because PHP source is "open", the check can be taken out. Personally, I don't like module developers who do this and I try not to buy their modules.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more about software licensing methods than about Magento help specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way which works more or less is ioncubing your module. Then you are able to implement some sort of license which can not be just removed.

If your module is ioncubed I don't use it, because ioncubed modules are a security risk.

Comment: Also from my experience - ioncube in your PHP means a much slower PHP execution

Comment: Afaik this is fixed in the newest version. But afaik there are still problems with xdebug.

Comment: Thanks for answer! If it's off topic, where should I ask? I saw some module company protect their module with serial number. Is ioncube (which I dislike) only option? Is there anyway to use serial number like the module company?

Comment: PHP is open source. If you don't protect your source code, everyone can remove the license check.